# Text Suggestion for the given topics.

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

Can anyone suggest me a suitable text(s) for the given topics ?

**Sample Surveys and Design of Experiments:**

Sampling and non-sampling errors. Conventional
sampling techniques (SRSWR/SRSWOR, stratified random sampling, systematic sampling).

Ratio and regression methods of estimation.

ANOVA and ANOCOVA. Basic designs such as CRD, RBD, LSD and their analyses. Missing
plot technique. $2^n$ (n $\leq$ 5) Factorial experiments and their construction and analysis. Total and partial confounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good modern text on design experiments is the one by Gary
Oehlert. It is available in hard back, but the author has posted
a PDF online, so you can look at it for free. I have never taught
out of this book, but I have used it for examples and as a reference.
Data are limited in scope, but real.

A traditional treatment of DOS is included in the Ott & Longnecker:
Statistical Methods and Data Analysis. The latest edition is very
expensive, but earlier editions are OK and much cheaper. I have
taught out this book many times. Treatments are straightforward.
You may be able to look at a copy at a local university library.
Computer printouts from various statistical software packages are
shown throughout. The topics you want are scattered throughout
the book, but chapter/section headings and the index will guide you to the
right places. This book is oriented towards applications, but the
data are mainly contrived.

Montgomery has several books on related topics. They are widely
used, possibly mainly in engineering programs.

An excellent classic book is by Scheffe. It uses mainly a linear
algebra approach. This book pretty much pre-dates the computer era.

Another very nice older book is the one by K. A. Brownlee: Statistical theory and methodology in science and engineering. Applied emphasis. A
distinguishing feature is that it uses only real data.

I will not make recommendations for books on sample surveys because
I have not taught a course targeting just that topic for some time.